# C parsing strings into separate variables without delimiters?

Tags: c, string

I am taking in a file and reading its contents, then I need to separate it into two different strings. I am having a problem though, because the data is a wall of text. For the life of me I cannot get it to work. I have the file opening correctly and the data is coming in as a single string called 'arr' with a length variable 'alen', but it is in a format like this:

```
      #Test1.10.5TestSubjectXNum1
```

I need it to be broken into:

```
str1 = Test1.10.5
str2 = TestSubjectXNum1
```

So far, this is what I have done:

```
char *str1 = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char));
char *str2 = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char));

for(j = 1; j < alen; j++) {

    if(s1 == 0) {

      *str1 = (char *) realloc(size_t + sizeof(char);
       str_append(str1, arr[j]);

    } else {

      *str2 = (char *) realloc(size_t + sizeof(char);
       str_append(str2, arr[j]);        

    }

}
```

's1' is a flag I'm trying to use to tell it to differentiate between the 2 parts of the string, and I've been trying to flip it when arr[j] is not a number, but arr[j - 1] was, but I cannot figure out how to do that in c.

How do you divide a string in this manner in c, without having spaces/commas to use as delimeters?

Comment: I assume you count `'.'` as a number character, otherwise it'll split into `"Test1"` and `".10.5TestSubjectXNum1"`. In general, you can either use a regex library, or just write out the code corresponding to the regex. The exact regex to use depends on how you want to split the strings.

Comment: what is the delimiter of the string you search? `char *str1 = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char));` is wrong, it reserves only 1 char. If you append something there, your program is `undefined behavior`. Take a look for `regexp`. If you need a working program to do the job, take a look for `awk`

Comment: does my edit help with allocation?

Comment: @ShawnKarber -  Is there any reason not to use a period as a delimiter? I ask, because this is exactly how we do it, so why not get the computer to approach it the same way?

Comment: i don't think you gave the original program. this line `*str1 = (char *) realloc(size_t + sizeof(char);` has multiple mistakes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have the entire string in memory, you can decide where to split the string first, and then allocate two arrays and copy the parts into them.

One way to find the split location is to run a loop looking for the first letter after seeing a digit:

```
char *str = "#Test1.10.5TestSubjectXNum1";
size_t splitPos = 0;
int seenDigitFlag = 0;
// Go through the string character by character
while (str[splitPos]) {
    // If we see a digit, set the flag
    seenDigitFlag |= isdigit(str[splitPos]);
    // If after seeing a digit we see a letter, end the loop:
    // we have our split point.
    if (isalpha(str[splitPos]) && seenDigitFlag) {
        break;
    }
    splitPos++;
}
// The rest is simple math: compute the length of the first substring
char *str1 = malloc(splitPos+1);
// Copy the content, and set null terminator
memcpy(str1, str, splitPos);
str1[splitPos] = '\0';
// Compute the length of the second substring
size_t rest = strlen(str)-splitPos;
// We can use `strcpy` instead of `memcpy`
// because the second substring is null-terminated
char *str2 = malloc(rest+1);
strcpy(str2, &str[splitPos]);
printf("'%s' '%s'", str1, str2);
```

Once you've got the split point, the rest is very simple: the only thing you need to remember is allocating an extra character for your null terminator.

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/a7k2Hb)

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I'd go about it.

Basically, I'd scan backwards from the end of the string to locate the first instance of a period. From there, I'd scan forwards looking for the first non-digit. Once done, it's just a matter of copy the second string, then allocate memory for and copy the first.

Here's a full example:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

void breakString(const char *str, char **str1, char **str2)
{
    char *period2Pos, *str2Start;

    // locate the last '.' character
    period2Pos = strrchr(str, '.');
    // point to next char
    str2Start = period2Pos+1;

    // keep moving forwards until the current char is not a digit
    // dont know how many digits the number will have, so just keep scanning
    // for something that's not a digit.
    while( isdigit( *str2Start ) )
        str2Start++;

    // from this point onwards, the text should go into str2
    *str2 = strdup(str2Start);

    // anything before this point should be measured, allocated and copied
    *str1 = (char*)calloc(str2Start-str + 1, 1);
    strncpy(*str1, str, str2Start-str);
}

int main()
{
    const char *str = "#Test1.10.5TestSubjectXNum1";
    char *str1, *str2;
    breakString(str, &str1, &str2);
    printf("str1: %s\n", str1);
    printf("str2: %s\n", str2);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would code it in this way though.

```
char *str="string you want to split";
char *str1;
char *str2;
int state;
char *ptr;
char *end;
int str1_tail;
int str2_tail;

void init() {
    int size = strlen(str) + 1;
    end = str + size;
    str1 = malloc(size);
    str2 = malloc(size);
    str1_tail = 0;
    str2_tail = 0;
    ptr = str;
    state = 0;
}


void str1_letter() {
    if (isdigit(*ptr))
        state = 1;
    str1[str1_tail++] = *ptr;
}

void str1_digit() {
    if (! isdigit(*ptr)) {
        state = 2;
        str2[str2_tail++] = *ptr;
        str1[str1_tail] = '\0';
    }
    else {
        str1[str1_tail++] = *ptr;
    }
}

void str2_copy() {
    str2[str2_tail++] = *ptr;
}

void (*work_table[])() = {
    str1_letter;
    str1_digit;
    str2_copy;
};

void parse() {
    init();
    for (; ptr < end; ptr++)
        (*work_table[state])();
    str2[str2_tail] = '\0';
}
```

then just call:

```
parse();
```

additionally, call `bzero(3)` after `malloc` allows you to be lazy and the code should be more robust(if you are working on Linux environment).

Comment: Seems like a reasonably flexible system, nice job. If you were even more lazy (and saw the note about bzero being deprecated and finally, removed from the POSIX standard: http://linux.die.net/man/3/bzero), wouldn't you just use `calloc` and both allocate and zero the memory in one go?

Comment: @enhzflep oh Jesus, i didn't know `bzero` is deprecated. i used it a lot before. thanks.